# Unable to iterate xml and create a dictionary with desired attribute in python

Tags: python, xml

I am pretty new in python and xml. Actually, I am trying to extract two attributes (vehicle-brand, car-definition) values and create a dictionary. I am able to iterate over only one attribute at a time, but my goal is to iterate two attributes together so that I can create a dictionary.

My desired output is `{"BMW":"C1","FORD":"C2","TOYOTA":"k1"}`

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def cars():
    str1='''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vehicles xmlns:xsi="https://cars.com" >
  <vehicle>
        <vehicle-brand>BMW</vehicle-brand>
    <cars>
        <car>
            <car-type>MID</car-type>
            <car-definition>C1</car-definition>
        </car>
    </cars>
  </vehicle>
 <vehicle>
    <vehicle-brand>FORD</vehicle-brand>
    <cars>
        <car>
            <car-type>LARGE</car-type> 
            <car-definition>C2</car-definition>
        </car>
    </cars>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
            <vehicle-brand>TOYOTA</vehicle-brand>
            <cars>
                <car>
                    <car-type>SMALL</car-type> 
                    <car-definition>K1</car-definition>
                </car>
            </cars>
    </vehicle>
</vehicles>'''

    try:
        e = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(str1))
        for elt in e.iter('car-definition'):
        print(elt.tag, elt.text)      
  
    except Exception as e:
       print("error")
       raise e
```

Comment: If you have two lists in python, you can create a dictionary by writing: dict(zip(list1,list2)). If you're already able to read in the attributes one by one, this may be an option for you

Comment: I have only xml file / xml string.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a dict comprehension that iterates across each `<car>` descendant under each `<vehicle>`, retrieving element text for key-value pair of dictionary:

```py
xml_dict = {
    veh.find("vehicle-brand").text: car.find("car-definition").text
    for veh in doc.iterfind("vehicle")   
    for car in veh.iterfind("cars/car") 
}

xml_dict
{'BMW': 'C1', 'FORD': 'C2', 'TOYOTA': 'K1'}
```

Since `<cars>` can expand to many multiple per `<vehicle>`, nest lists of cars for each distinct vehicle:

```py
xml_dict = {
    veh.find("vehicle-brand").text: 
        [car.find("car-definition").text 
         for car in veh.iterfind("cars/car")]
    for veh in doc.iterfind("vehicle") 
}

xml_dict
{'BMW': ['C1'], 'FORD': ['C2'], 'TOYOTA': ['K1']}
```